# django xhtml2pdf table border issue

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

I'm using xhtml2pdf with Django to generate a PDF with a table that runs over multiple pages. I can't seem to get the table body `<tbody>` to generate a border. I am not trying to get a border around the whole table including header `<thead>`, just the main body. I've been able to generate left and right borders by adding style to `<td>`, and a bottom border to `<thead>` so that it appears that the tbody has borders on 3 sides, leaving only the `<tbody>` bottom. but i suspect this is really a hack and not the correct way to get a full border around `<tbody>`. In any event I'm left stuck with this part solution and no bottom border. I've tried applying lots of css via id's classes and elements. has anyone had any experience successfully implementing table borders with xhtml2pdf in Django and could kindly offer me some guidance? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Does the same table work in actual HTML? <tbody> and <tr> elements can only have borders when the table is in collapsed borders mode.

Comment: Hi Mr Lister, thanks for your response. Yes the table works in HTML and I tried your suggestion of collapsed borders mode. The borders are rendering but for each row, not only for the outside edge of the table. Possibly due to my data being rendered into the table via a for loop. I've opted to use another hack, and added an if counter inside the loop to use modified styling for those rows that are the last row on each page the table runs over.